# Using chef to install Open JDK 8 on Raspberry PI 3 with Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, raspberry-pi, chef-infra, apt-get

I want to install Open JDK 8 on my Rarpberry PI 3 running Ubuntu MATE 16.04

I've an internet connection using corporate Proxy that requires a certificate for HTTPS connection.

Trying the Supemarket Java recipe (https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java) i'm getting errors while trying to add PPA.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the errors you get?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting an error for a PPA (Personal Package Archives), make sure that that package is built and published as an apt repository. It may solve your problem.

PS: You can be more specific about what kind of errors you are getting so that we can help you more as much as possible.

PPS: Another option for RPi: Get the tar files and install the Java 8 manually. Take a look at this URL: http://www.rpiblog.com/2014/03/installing-oracle-jdk-8-on-raspberry-pi.html